# Wireless Canon MG6250 printer not found

Tags: printer

The `Add Printer` dialog under `Printers` is unable to find my Wireless Canon MG6250 printer.

I know the IP address but still it's not detected.
I can surf to the web-interface of the printer on the IP.

What more can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hardware specific questions can be very hard to debug. Are you entering the (working) IP Address into the `Add Printer` dialog at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but to add a printer you have to work like that

1. Check that your printer is connected to the network
2. search **printer** in the app launcher
3. on the window click on the **+** at the bottom left

Now at the time of writing we are at version 5.1 of elementary OS and personally with a printer Canon MP620 connected in networks by Wifi, I did not need to install driver